# Problems when upgrading from typeahead 2.1 to new version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

The initial function looks like this:

```
    function addressTypeaheadInitialize() {
        $('.address').typeahead().on('keyup', function(ev) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            if ($.inArray(ev.keyCode, [ 40, 38, 9, 13, 27 ]) != -1) {
                return;
            }
            var self = $(this);
            self.data('typeahead').source = [];
            if (!self.data('active') && self.val().length > 0) {
                self.data('active', true);
                self.addClass('hint-loading');
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'post',
                    url : '/jetty/typeahead_address',
                    data : {
                        query : this.value
                    }, /*
                     * ie {'TYPE':$ (this).attr('data-input-type'),
                     * 'VAR2','test2'}
                     */
                    dataType : 'json',
                    cache : false,
                    success : function(data) {
                        self.data('active', true);
                        var source = [], highlights = [], i = data.source.length;
                        while (i--) {
                            source[i] = data.source[i];
                            highlights[i] = data.highlights[i];
                        }
                        self.data('typeahead').highlighter = function(item) {
                            var id = source.indexOf(item);
                            return highlights[id];
                        };
                        self.data('typeahead').source = source;
                        self.trigger('keyup');
                        self.data('active', false);
                        self.removeClass('hint-loading');
                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        self.removeClass('hint-loading');
                    }
                });
                self.data('active', false);
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried to make it work on new typeahead this way:

```
  function addressTypeaheadInitialize() {
    var suggestions = function(query, cb) {
             $.ajax({
                type : 'post',
                url : '/jetty/typeahead_address',
                data : {
                    query : query
                }, 
                dataType : 'json',
                cache : false,
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                     var source = [], highlights = [], i = data.source.length;
                    while (i--) {
                        source[i] = data.source[i];
                        highlights[i] = data.highlights[i];
                    }
                    cb(source);
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
                }
            });
    }

    var options = {
        highlighter : function(item) {
                        var id = source.indexOf(item)
                        return highlights[id];
        },
        source: suggestions,
    }
    $('.address').typeahead(null, options);
}
```

Now I can't even input any text in the form! What am I doing wrong?